# Social Media Content Rights

Tags: copyright, social-media

Is it possible to have a social media site that leaves the copyright with the creator, but by posting gives the site posting rights? Is this common?

Answer (score 3):

Almost every site does this.  See, for example, the bottom of your screen and read the terms and conditions linked in this text:

> user contributions licensed under [cc by-sa 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) with attribution required